# Number of monotically increasing functions where $f(k) = l$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

How many monotically functions $f: \{1,2, ..., m\} \rightarrow \{1,2, ..., n\}$ are there if $f(k) = l$, where $1 \le k \le m$ and $1 \le l \le n$?

I tried to compute as answer in [counting monotonically increasing functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552233/counting-monotonically-increasing-functions/1552568#1552568) and I has this result: ${{(k-1)+(l-1)} \choose {l-1}} \cdot { {(m-k)+(n-l)} \choose {n-l}}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it’s correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you :) At least one positive information for me today

Comment: And it’s a comment that I like to make! `:-)`